# How to calculate sum of column in Datagridview with empty cells in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm not getting the sum of a column when there is an empty cells in my column, but when there is no empty it works fine.

What i want is to get the sum of a column even there is a empty cells

heres my code:

```
    Dim rows As Integer = 0
    Dim total_tax_withheld_map As Double

    Try
        Do Until rows = DataGridView4.RowCount
            Dim Tax_Withheld As Double = DataGridView4.Rows(rows).Cells(6).Value
            total_tax_withheld_map = total_tax_withheld_map + Tax_Withheld
            rows = rows + 1
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    lblamountmap.Text = total_tax_withheld_map
    Dim dblValuemap As Double = total_tax_withheld_map
    lblamountmap.Text = (dblValuemap.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: First things first, get rid of that `Try...Catch` block.  There's no good reason to expect an exception there and you should NEVER simply ignore unexpected exceptions.

Comment: The way to ignore empty cells is to check whether the cell is empty first and then only use it if it's not. Don't just assign the `Value` of the cell to a `Double` variable if it might not be a `Double`.  Test whether the `.Value Is Nothing` and/or `.Value Is DBNull.Value`, depending on whether the grid is bound or not, and then only assign it to a `Double` variable if it is NOT either of those things.

Comment: You should also turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and in the IDE options as well, so it is `On` by default for future projects.

Comment: Also, use the right loop for the job.  This is not a situation for a `Do` loop.  You should be using either a `For` or `For Each` loop in this case.

Comment: The fact that you tagged this question MySQL (I removed that tag because it is irrelevant to the actual question you asked) suggest that you actually have a `DataTable` bound to your grid.  In that case, you should not be using the grid for this at all.  The `DataTable` has a `Compute` method for evaluating aggregate functions and it will handle NULLs automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check if the cell has a null value before adding it 
Like this:

```
Dim rows As Integer = 0
Dim total_tax_withheld_map As Double

Try
    Do Until rows = DataGridView4.RowCount
        If (Not DataGridView4.Rows(rows).Cells(6).Value = Null) Then
            Dim Tax_Withheld As Double = DataGridView4.Rows(rows).Cells(6).Value
            total_tax_withheld_map = total_tax_withheld_map + Tax_Withheld
        End If
        rows = rows + 1
    Loop
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

lblamountmap.Text = total_tax_withheld_map
Dim dblValuemap As Double = total_tax_withheld_map
lblamountmap.Text = (dblValuemap.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: Change the `Nothing` to `Null`

Comment: This will error out if there's an alphabetical string in column 6.  But again, I have no idea if that's an issue in this case.

Comment: If you opt to use this:  The try/catch is unnecessary, Do Until should be For Each, There's no reason to double-set your text field and Doubles should be parsed not inferred via conversion if there's a concern of alphabetical values.  dblValuemap is unnecessary, just use total_tax_withheld_map.